# HP-UX: Threads per process

Tags: multithreading, hp-ux

is there a command on HP-UX to check and view all the threads related to a process/task.

ps -m isn't supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display a stack trace of the threads belonging to a particular process using pstack. It will also give you the LWPID (thread ID). For example:

```
$ whereis pstack
pstack: /usr/ccs/bin/pstack /usr/share/man/man1.Z/pstack.1

$ ps -ef|grep snmpAgt|grep -v grep
   utest 27447     1  0  Aug 26  ?        1544:45 /opt/java6/bin/IA64N/java -DsnmpAgtCfg=./etc/snmpAgt.cfg -Duser.timezone=GMT+8 com.hp.snmpagt.main.SnmpAgtMain

$ pstack 27447|head -30           
27447:  /opt/java6/bin/IA64N/java

--------------------------------  lwpid : 5549697   -------------------------------

 0: 60000000c0380670 : _nanosleep_sys() + 0x30 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libc.so.1)
 1: 60000000c038f360 : nanosleep() + 0xa0 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libc.so.1)
 2: 60000000c89c4ac0 : _Z8os_sleepxb() + 0xa90 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
 3: 60000000c89d5140 : _ZN2os5sleepEP6Threadxb() + 0x200 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
 4: 60000000c83b51a0 : JVM_Sleep() + 0x340 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
 5: 2000000073400ed0 : (unknown) () (unknown)

--------------------------------  lwpid : 5549698   -------------------------------

 0: 60000000c0379e50 : __ksleep() + 0x30 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libc.so.1)
 1: 60000000c013aa10 : __mxn_sleep() + 0xaf0 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so.1)
 2: 60000000c00d1f50 : pthread_cond_wait() + 0xdd0 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so.1)
 3: 60000000c00d1210 : pthread_cond_wait() + 0x90 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so.1)
 4: 60000000c89c1880 : _Z13thread_helperPv() + 0x3b0 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
 5: 60000000c00e2060 : __pthread_bound_body() + 0x170 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so.1)

--------------------------------  lwpid : 5549699   -------------------------------

 0: 60000000c0379e50 : __ksleep() + 0x30 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libc.so.1)
 1: 60000000c013aa10 : __mxn_sleep() + 0xaf0 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so.1)
 2: 60000000c00d1f50 : pthread_cond_wait() + 0xdd0 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so.1)
 3: 60000000c00d1210 : pthread_cond_wait() + 0x90 (/usr/lib/hpux32/libpthread.so.1)
 4: 60000000c89e2bb0 : _ZN2os13PlatformEvent4parkEv() + 0x330 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
 5: 60000000c8947df0 : _ZN7Monitor5IWaitEP6Threadx() + 0x1a0 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
 6: 60000000c8948c30 : _ZN7Monitor4waitEblb() + 0x2b0 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
 7: 60000000c80ab6c0 : _ZN13GCTaskManager8get_taskEj() + 0xa0 (/opt/java6/jre/lib/IA64N/server/libjvm.so)
```

Comment: Could you please include an explanation too?

Answer (score 0):

use glance

1. % glance
2. SlctProc (F6)
3. Enter PID (14065) : **14389**
4. **G**

```
... 

Thread List PID: 14389, xxxxx          PPID: 14241 euid:   112 User: xxxxxxx
            CPU Util    CPU Tm      Phys          Logl                    Block
  TID    ( 600x% max)    Cum       IO Rate      IO Rate   Scheduler  Pri   On
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
7744076    0.0/   0.0    21.1    0.0/   0.0    0.0/   0.0      HPUX  168  SLEEP
7745285    0.0/   0.0     0.0    0.0/   0.0    0.0/   0.0      HPUX  152  SOCKT
7745286    0.0/   0.0     0.0    0.0/   0.0    0.0/   0.0      HPUX  154  SOCKT
7745287    1.5/   1.7 12092.2    0.0/   0.0    0.5/   1.4      HPUX  154  SLEEP
7745288    0.0/   0.0    46.7    0.0/   0.0    0.0/   0.0      HPUX  154  SLEEP
7745290    0.0/   0.0   578.4    0.0/   0.0    2.3/   0.0      HPUX  168  SLEEP
6471709    0.0/   0.0     0.0    0.0/   0.0    0.0/   0.0      HPUX  152  JOBCL
```